# Karatsuba multiplication error for large integers in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, multiplication

I've been trying to implement the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) in Python3 in the following way:

```
def karatsuba(num1,num2):
    n_max = max(len(str(int(num1))), len(str(int(num2))))
    if n_max == 1:
        return int(num1*num2)

    n = n_max + n_max%2

    a = num1//10**(n/2)
    b = num1%10**(n/2)
    c = num2//10**(n/2)
    d = num2%10**(n/2)

    t1 = karatsuba(a,c)
    t3 = karatsuba(b,d)
    t2 = karatsuba(a+b,c+d) - t1 - t3

    return int(t1*10**n + t2*10**(n/2) + t3)
```

While the function works for small products, it fails for ones that exceed 18 digits. One can see this by running, say,

```
import random

for i in range(1,12):
    a = random.randint(10**i, 10**(i+1)-1)
    b = random.randint(10**i, 10**(i+1)-1)
    print(f"{len(str(a*b))} digits, error: {abs(a*b - karatsuba(a,b))}")
```

I would appreciate if someone could explain what is the root of this problem and, if possible, how could this code be modified to fix it. My best guess is that some round-off error is committed by Python at some point. That said, I don't really know how `int` fundamentally works in this language.

Comment: `max(len(str(int(num1))), len(str(int(num2))))` Probably `num1` and `num2` are already int, so this could be simplified a bit? Likewise, `return int(num1*num2)` could be simplified to `return num1 * num2`

Comment: Sounds like you're getting a floating point intermediate result somewhere - probably due to one of those uses of `/` instead of `//`.  Get rid of that `int()` at the end, it's only covering up the problem.

Comment: You are calculating the expression `10**(n/2)` six times in the body of the function. Instead you could calculate it once and store the result in a variable: `p = 10 ** ((n_max + 1) // 2)`. Then use `p` rather than `10**(n/2)` throughout your code.

Comment: @jasonharper Replacing `/` with `//` where the fraction is expected and guaranteed to be an integer solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Stef That's a good point! Thanks!

Comment: @Stef On the point of converting `num1` and `num2` to `int`, it makes sense to get rid of it in the recursive calls of the function, since the function does return an `int`. However, in the initial call where user might pass a `float`, this might break the whole algorithm. Is there a way to limit some section of code only for non-recursive calls?

Comment: @strider No, usually if you want your recursive function to be different than the function seen by the user, you need to wrap it in another function. I.e., you have two functions, one is called `karatsuba` and the other `karatsuba_helper`; all the actual code is in `karatsuba_helper`; and `karatsuba` contains only a few checks or preprocessing, followed by a call to `karatsuba_helper`.

Comment: @Stef That makes sense. Thanks for help!

Comment: Note that according to the linked article `t2 = karatsuba(a+b,c+d) - t1 - t3` can overflow and is better implemented as `t2 = karatsuba(a-b,c-d) + t1 + t3`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Can't overflow in Python, though.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks for pointing out a potential problem. It also made me realize that the function, as presented, does not work for negative inputs, which prevents just replacing the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `n//2` instead of `n/2` to stay with `int`s and avoid that precision loss due to that `float` value.

Comment: That works! So I guess the lesson here is just to make sure to use `x//y` or `int(x/y)` when the fraction is expected to be an integer. Thanks!

Comment: @strider Not `int(x/y)`. For example for `x, y = 10**30, 10`, that computes [`99999999999999991433150857216`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v0JHoVLBVsHQQEvL2EAHSHMVFGXmlWhU6OtXakLZEH6lpub//wA).

Comment: Right! The float division is performed first and thus it introduces a numerical error that that `int()` just propagates. Thanks!